# PhpStorm + Xdebug: Connection established, no Debug window popup in PhpStorm

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm struggling to get PhpStorm and Xdebug to play nicely on a specific Vagrant VM.

*How can I effectively track down and resolve the issue in connecting PhpStorm and Xdebug for this VM?*

While I can see that PhpStorm and Xdebug are communicating to a degree, the connection from Xdebug does not launch PhpStorm's debug window, and it's not possible to use PhpStorm's debugging capabilities.

The combination of tools in question is:

- Vagrant VM with Ubuntu 16-04
- PHP 7.1 with php-xdebug 2.7
- PhpStorm 2018.2.1
- Firefox Xdebug Helper extension
- Drupal 8.6.10
- Breakpoint is inserted in `index.php` at line 16.

I'm able to get this Vagrant VM to connect to Atom's `php-debug` Xdebug integration. I'm also able to get this PhpStorm to connect to other Vagrant instance's Xdebug!

Xdebug config from the server in question:

```
# xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
# xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.remote_autostart = off
# xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.2.2 # IP of the host system
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I see output in the logfile `/tmp/xdebug.log` when using this configuration.

- With Xdebug Helper to "Disable", the page loads in the browser. No log entries are recorded to `/tmp/xdebug.log`.
- With PhpStorm set to "Stop listening for PHP Debug connections", the page loads in the browser. No log entries are recorded to `/tmp/xdebug.log`.
- With Xdebug Helper set to "Debug" and PhpStorm set to "Start listening for PHP debug connections", the page is paused as though the breakpoint is recognised. However, PhpStorm does not bring up a debug window, so it's not possible to debug. The following is logged to `/tmp/xdebug.log`:

```
[8264] Log opened at 2019-03-14 01:39:02
[8264] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.0.2.2:9000.
[8264] I: Connected to client. :-)
[8264] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/drupal/web/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.1.26-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="8264" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.7.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[8264]
[8264] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- stdout -i 6 -c 1
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="6" success="1"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- status -i 7
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="7" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- step_into -i 8
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="8" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/drupal/web/index.php" lineno="14"></xdebug:message></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- eval -i 9 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="9"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- eval -i 10 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="10"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- eval -i 11 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[bG9jYWxob3N0]]></property></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- eval -i 12 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="string" size="4" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[ODAwMA==]]></property></response>
[8264]
[8264] <- eval -i 13 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
[8264] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="string" size="1" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[Lw==]]></property></response>
[8264]
```

If I then click "Stop listening for PHP debug connections", I immediately see the following logged to `/tmp/xdebug.log`:

```
[8264] <- run -i 14
```

Then that's quickly followed by [this logged output](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/b7f2392f5e7118a2d222f4461eefc8d4) (too large for this question), and the page and resources load as per before.

**How can I effectively track down and resolve the issue in connecting PhpStorm and Xdebug for this VM?**

PhpStorm > Languages > PHP:

[image: PhpStorm > Languages > PHP]

PhpStorm > Languages > PHP > Debug:
[image: PhpStorm > Languages > PHP > Debug]

Comment: Are you getting any messages in PhpStorm (e.g. "debug seesion finished without being paused" in Event Log)? Open File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers & delete all server configurations you have (if it's ok for you). Then start debugging again - PhpStorm should prompt you a window about an incoming debug connection & options to configure path mappings - please check that path mappings are correct there.

Comment: I went through the path mapping process a couple of times, including deleting server configs, and that didn't resolve it. I also found the PhpStorm debug log interface and will add that information to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using PhpStorm 2018.2.x with Xdebug 2.7.

Either upgrade PhpStorm to the latest stable 2018.3.x or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x

The problem is in recently changed XML namespace in Xdebug protocol, as of Xdebug 2.7 (`https` instead of `http`). It's fixed/supported since PhpStorm 2018.3.0 (see [WI-43622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622)).

Comment: Thanks, and thanks also for correcting the capitalisation of PhpStorm through the question. I'll give this a try shortly!

Comment: This fixed it. I'm so grateful for you taking the time to answer this. Are you able to give a reference to where I might have found this information on PhpStorm's website? I just checked [What's new in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/) (for 2018.3, released Nov 2018) notes and didn't spot any reference to a change in Xdebug support there.

Comment: Check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622 or https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1637

Comment: Much appreciated! I'm so happy to see it working on this VM now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uncommenting `# xdebug.remote_connect_back = on`?

We have found that it is always required for working between PhpStorm and XDEBUG. Or maybe better:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

We used the above in it our Vagrant solution WPLib Box which we specifically built to make XDEBUG easy with PhpStorm.

I would show it to you in a link but that repo is private. However we recently switched to Docker inside Vagrant and our Docker repo is public os here is [our `xdebug.ini` file](https://github.com/wplib/php-docker/blob/master/7.2.6/files/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini) for our PHP 7.2.6 Docker container.

Hope this helps solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried commenting that out. It didn't resolve the behaviour. Either way, Xdebug seems to want to connect to the host system on 10.0.2.2, but PhpStorm reports the connection as originating from 127.0.0.1. Thanks for the xdebug.ini link, I'll investigate that and the other replies!