# After updating Ubuntu, the request began to hang when the listener is enabled in PhpStorm Xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, php-7.3

All settings are normal. I went through https://xdebug.org/wizard.php. phpize matched. I decided to reinstall it. My phpize with PHP 7.3 coincided with wizard. In `phpinfo()` Xdebug is displayed. In `php -v` as well. Even more, in PhpStorm it catches the connection.

The problem is that when I send a request to the server, with the listener turned on, my request does not reach the breakpoint, the request just hangs and nothing happens.

What could be the problem? Does anybody knows?

In general, I have no idea what could be the problem. I really need your help, help who knows what the trouble may be.

1. I went through all the hints from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
2. In phpinfo() output everything is OK.
3. Everything seems to be fine in the PhpStorm settings too. I did not change them, I always worked with those who stand now.

Comment: After I turn off the listener, the request immediately passes.

Comment: My php.ini

[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable = On;
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 6;
xdebug.remote_enable = On;
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1;
xdebug.remote_port = 9009;
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp;
xdebug.idekey = phpstorm;
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1;
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1;
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0;
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp/xdebug/profiler/;
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1;
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1;

Comment: After sending the request, the stop button near the listener does not light up.

Comment: I turned on "Break at first line in PHP scripts"
After that I caught the first line of my application with debager. But when I pressed F 8, the debager did not reach my ripping point, but hung up as before. In an endless pause.

Comment: If you put the maximum connections in the settings of xdebug phpstorm for example 5-7, then the debager will stop in the first line of the application, but then when you press F 8, then in the debager panel it will say "Connected"

Comment: What is your PhpStorm and Xdebug versions?

Comment: Right now it sounds like you have PhpStorm 2018.2 or OLDER. You need 2018.3.x or freshly released 2019.1 as Xdebug 2.7 (which is the one that works with PHP 7.3) had changes in protocol and it's fixed in 2018.3 only. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55161822/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159290/783119